# Get total record count for SqlAlchemy query result, which uses pagination(limit, offset)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am using `sqlalchemy` query with `limit` and `offset.` Now I need to get the `total count` of the query result.

For now I am using count query and limit query separately and getting the results. Is there any efficient way to get the count in a single sqlalchemy query.

Here is the sample of currently what I am using,

```
# getting total count
docs_count = DB_SESSION.query(Documents).count()

# using limit and offset
docs_list = DB_SESSION.query(Documents).limit(10).offset(0)
```

Now is it possible to combine this into a single query, or there any efficient method to do this. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue.
What I did is to add the count operation into the query through an 'over' clause as follow:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

docs_query = DB_SESSION.query(Documents,func.count(Documents.id).over().label("total"))
docs_query = docs_query.limit(10).offset(0)
docs_results = docs_query.all()
if len(docs_results) > 0 :
    docs_list= docs_results[0]
    docs_count= docs_results[0][1]
```

SQLAlchemy info :

- count:
  https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.count
- over:
  https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.over

I don't know if it is the best way to do it but it is a bit faster than what you have done. Hope it will help you or someone else.